# Existe algum método para retornar a URL do arquivo escolhido em um elemento de entrada "file"?

Tags: javascript

O que eu gostaria é que, por exemplo, ao clicar no elemento de entrada do tipo `file` (`input type="file"`) ele me retornasse a `URL` completa do arquivo que o usuário escolheu, apenas isso! para depois subsequente eu colocar na minha aplicação que estou desenvolvendo, mas para isso preciso saber se existe algum método ou propriedade no *JavaScript* que me retorne a *URL* do arquivo escolhido.

Answer (score 0):

Não. Quando você escolhe um arquivo através de um `input[type="file"]`, o navegador torna disponível os bytes desse arquivo para que sejam enviados a um servidor na web. Não existe uma forma nativa de fazer esse upload pra web e gerar uma URL.

O que você pode fazer é uma aplicação que recebe esse arquivo via upload, salva em um diretório público na web e devolve a URL completa (domínio + diretório + nome do arquivo).